# Google Chrome Constantly Locking Up

Tags: google-chrome, freeze

Here’s my problem. I have Chrome 43.0.2357.81 m installed on three different computers: My personal desktop, my personal laptop, and my company workstation. On my two personal computers it’s virtually impossible for me to use YouTube, Netflix, or Google Images without Chrome going unresponsive for 10-15 seconds and snapping back. These are the main culprits, but sometimes it locks up in seemingly random places like the Google home page and Facebook, and other times I can watch YouTube videos and browse google images without issue for days at a time. It’s the lack of a pattern that frustrates me the most.

My workstation has the same version of Chrome and has no issues doing anything, so I don’t think it’s a version specific issue. I’ve tried the usual fixes, uninstalling and reinstalling, clearing all browsing data, installing Windows updates, and disabling all extensions all to no avail. I’m at a loss and any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: From my experience I find Chrome uses a lot of resources. Have you tried using Firefox? I have had good experience with it so far on my lower resource machines. I would recommend trying to run Firefox instead of Chrome to see if it increases performance.

Comment: @DanielHayes I have used Firefox, and it does help. I don't feel like this is a performance issue of Chrome using too many resources [although I agree with you that it has a much higher footprint than FF] this is a more acute problem than that. Switching to Firefox is plan C because I'm pretty attached to Chrome.